# How to scrape the text by categories and make a json file?

Tags: json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

We scrape the website [www.theft-alerts.com](http://www.theft-alerts.com). Now we get all the text.

```
connection = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.theft-alerts.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(connection.read().replace("<br>","\n"), "html.parser")

theftalerts = []
for sp in soup.select("table div.itemspacingmodified"):
    for wd in sp.select("div.itemindentmodified"):
        text = wd.text
        if not text.startswith("Images :"):
            print(text)

with open("theft-alerts.json", 'w') as outFile:
    json.dump(theftalerts, outFile, indent=2)
```

Output:

```
STOLEN : A LARGE TAYLORS OF LOUGHBOROUGH BELL
Stolen from Bromyard on 7 August 2014
Item : The bell has a diameter of 37 1/2" is approx 3' tall weighs just shy of half a ton and was made by Taylor's of Loughborough in 1902. It is stamped with the numbers 232 and 11.

The bell had come from Co-operative Wholesale Society's Crumpsall Biscuit Works in Manchester.
Any info to : PC 2361. Tel 0300 333 3000
Messages : Send a message
Crime Ref : 22EJ / 50213D-14

No of items stolen : 1

Location : UK > Hereford & Worcs
Category : Shop, Pub, Church, Telephone Boxes & Bygones
ID : 84377
User : 1 ; Antique/Reclamation/Salvage Trade ;  (Administrator)
Date Created : 11 Aug 2014 15:27:57
Date Modified : 11 Aug 2014 15:37:21;
```

How can we categories the text for the JSON file. The JSON file is now empty.

Output JSON:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a list and append all dictionary objects that you create to the list. e.g:

```
import json

theftalerts = [];
atheftobject = {};
atheftobject['location'] = 'UK > Hereford & Worcs';
atheftobject['category'] = 'Shop, Pub, Church, Telephone Boxes & Bygones';
theftalerts.append(atheftobject);

atheftobject['location'] = 'UK';
atheftobject['category'] = 'Shop';
theftalerts.append(atheftobject);

with open("theft-alerts.json", 'w') as outFile:
        print(json.dump(theftalerts, outFile, indent=2))
```

After this run the `theft-alerts.json` will contain this json object:

```
[
  {
    "category": "Shop",
    "location": "UK"
  },
  {
    "category": "Shop",
    "location": "UK"
  }
]
```

You can play with this to generate your own JSON object. 
Checkout the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON output remains empty because your loop doesn't append to the list.

Here's how I would extract the category name:

```
theftalerts = []
for sp in soup.select("table div.itemspacingmodified"):
    item_text = "\n".join(
        [wd.text for wd in sp.select("div.itemindentmodified")
         if not wd.text.startswith("Images :")])
    category = sp.find(
        'span', {'class': 'itemsmall'}).text.split('\n')[1][11:]
    theftalerts.append({'text': item_text, 'category': category})
```